# How to get the client IP for a request in Embedded NettyJaxrsServer

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, netty, resteasy

I have created a standalone application using `NettyJaxrsServer`. In one scenario I want to get the IP of the request coming to the server. How do to do that.?

I have the pom here with dependency

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
 <artifactId>resteasy-netty</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I have created the `NettyJaxrsServer` using the following code.

```
public void createServer()
 {
     server = new NettyJaxrsServer();
     server.setDeployment(getDeployment());
     server.setPort(configuration.getPort());
     server.setSecurityDomain(null);  server.setRootResourcePath(configuration.getResourceRootPath());

}

public ResteasyDeployment getDeployment() {
    final ResteasyDeployment dp = new ResteasyDeployment();
    final Collection<Object> controllers = new ArrayList<Object>();
    controllers.add(ctx.getBean(TestIP.class));
    dp.getResources().addAll(controllers);

    return dp;
}
```

and my webservice class

```
@Path("/test")
@Component
public class TestIP {

    @GET
    @Path("/pingIp")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getAd( @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        return servletRequest.getRemoteAddr();
    }

}
```

while Encountering   `servletRequest.getRemoteAddr();` it throws the `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure` Exception. Please some body healp me to find out what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of trial and errors, the following code helped me to get the Client IP in the Service method..

```
@Path("/test")
@Component
public class TestIP {

    @GET
    @Path("/pingIp")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAd( @Context ChannelHandlerContext nioChannelContext) {
        return ((java.net.InetSocketAddress)nioChannelContext.getChannel().getRemoteAddress()).getAddress().getHostAddress();
    }

}
```